# How can I make a floating panel that disappears in full screen mode

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a panel that I want to float above all windows and appear in all spaces.  This is easily done with

```
[self.panel setLevel:kCGUtilityWindowLevel];
[self.window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
```

but now I want to be able to optionally hide the panel in full screen mode. I still want it to appear in all spaces when not in full screen mode.

I can't seem to find any set of options that will result in a floating panel, visible in all screens, but hidden in full screen mode.

It's possible I could detect when the system goes in to full screen mode and adjust the panel settings, but I was hoping for a more elegant behaviour setting.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what behavior you're looking for. Is there an Apple app you can think of that has panels that does exactly what you want? I was under the impression that floating panels shouldn't really be used anymore... it seems to me that in all of Apple's apps they've been moving away from floating panels to instead having the panels built into the side of the window. IE, in the most recent update to the iWork apps they got rid of the Inspector panel and now instead that functionality is stuck on the right side of the window.

Comment: My app (Keyboard Maestro) is a macro program.  It uses floating palettes as a way of triggering macros.  So they need to float above all application windows for this purpose (and they can also be specific to specific apps if the user desires).  But the user might want them visible in Safari, but hidden when watching a full screen video for example.  That is the behaviour I desire.

Answer (score 0):

According to DTS there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality.

I would still desperately like some sort of (legitimate) hack solution to this.  I don't like hacks in general, but sometimes they are necessary, as long as they can be made fail-safe.